# error while inserting data into hive using condition

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

hi I need to insert values into a new table (consist of 3 colunms) where I have a column named verad_id which has 250 values and now while inserting data i need to load all the values expect for 6 verad_id which has zero values for reage field.

example main table:-

```
verad_id   reage  value
 998        0      38
 8484       4      43
 998        3      33
 432        0      23
 233        43     26
 556        0      53
 432        9      33
```

now i need to insert values expect for   verad_id 998 and 432 which has reage value as 0

after inserting table should be like this

```
verad_id   reage  value
 8484       4      43
 998        3      33
 233        43     26
 556        0      53
 432        9      33
```

I have tried this but not working

tried case 1:-

```
insert into finaltable
select
verad_id,
reage,
value
from main_table where  verad_id = '998' or verad_id = '432' and reage != 0;
```

tried this but this query is not working

tried case 2:-

```
insert into finaltable
select
verad_id,
reage,
value
from main_table where  verad_id in ( '998' , '432') and reage != 0;
```

in this case I was able to load data of verad_id '998' and '432' with reage not equal to  0 here i am missing data of other verad_id.

can any one please help me with this

Comment: How important is the `value` column, should it have the value paired with the `reage` value or does this not matter?

Comment: @Peter yes value column is important as I need to do some aggressions on that column based on the value paired with  reage .

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple what you want to do is get grouped data from table `main_table` and each group sorted by the column `reage` in a `DESC` order.

Once you've got those results you wish to insert them into the table called `finaltalbe`

In this case you could use a subselect in which you define the order in which the results should be displayed, then select a group around that and MySQL will show the values of the first row in each grouped set.

```
INSERT INTO finaltable
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM main_table ORDER BY `reage` DESC) AS `sorted` GROUP BY `verad_id`;
```

this will result in the table `finaltable` with the following data

```
| verad_id | reage | value |
|----------|-------|-------|
|      233 |    43 |    26 |
|      432 |     9 |    33 |
|      556 |     0 |    53 |
|      998 |     3 |    33 |
|     8484 |     4 |    43 |
```